# Why do I see a spike in this transient?

Tags: mosfet, solar-cell, transient

I'm trying to measure the V/I curve of a solar panel by recording a capacitor charge curve. Here is the circuit:

[image: Measure circuit]

The DC source and R<sub>4</sub> simulate the solar panel (I know it's not an accurate model).
An ESP8266 drives the MOSFET gate high (3.3 V) for 1 ms and, during that period, it measures the U<sub>adc</sub> voltage. I'm getting unexpected results, so I've attached an oscilloscope to U<sub>ch1</sub> and U<sub>ch2</sub>, here is what I get:

[image: Transient captured by the oscilloscope]

The issue is caused by the spike when the gate pulse is applied. Here is a detailed view:

[image]

The measured R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is about 0.11 Ω @ 3.3 V and the capacitor's ESR should be 0.72 Ω according to the datasheet.

What could be the cause of the spike I see when I apply the gate voltage and how can I avoid it?

Comment: If you want a more accurate model of a solar panel, replace the voltage source an resistor combo with a current source in parallel with diode(s).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably caused by some stray inductance somewhere in your layout.

You could try to reduce the inductance, slow the MOSFET switching (for example, with a series gate resistor)- but that adds some stress to the MOSFET-  or just ignore the first bit of the waveform with your ADC.

Comment: I thought about inductances, but by adding them in the circuit, the transient has another shape. The strangest thing is that the voltage decreases rapidly, then rises again and there is no ringing. If I ignore the first bit of the waveform, I don't know the "initial" value of \$U_{C1}\$.

Comment: The resemblance between the two waveforms suggests something related to the ground connections.